# Neater ng-repeat syntax for keys only when iterating JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I use the `ng-repeat="(key, value)"` syntax to iterate a JSON object, but I never actually need the `value` variable when I'm working with checkboxes. Is there a neater way to do the following:

**EDIT:** HAML was confusing some, so here is plain HTML/angular:

```
<!-- "(key, val) in object" allows me to do everything, but value variable is wasted -->
<label ng-repeat="(attribute, value) in object">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="object[attribute]"/>
    {{attribute}}
</label>
```

Notice that I actually use `attribute` for the `ng-model` (which does not work properly when just binding to `value`) *and for the checkbox label*. There is no escaping the key here. What I do not need is the *value* variable.

It is true that you can do `ng-repeat: "value in object"`, but `value` does not bind properly on the checkbox, and, again, does not give me something to use for the label:

```
<!-- "val in object" does not give me a label for checkboxes, and does not bind correctly -->
<label ng-repeat="value in object">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="value"/> <!-- changing this checkbox does not update the parent scope -->
    {{attribute}} <!-- does not exist in scope -->
</label>
```

Here is a fiddle demonstrating the above: http://jsfiddle.net/Zb5bA/8/

Comment: you are using object[attribute1] while in ng-repeat your key is attribute, is it typo

Comment: It's a typo in the translated HTML, but does not affect the actual question. The HAML above is working in the browser, things just went wrong when I simplified my copy.paste

Comment: in place of ng-model="object[attribute]", you can write ng-model="value", so no need of attribute here

Comment: @JeetendraChauhan You misread my question, I am changing it to make it more clear. Do not respond again until I have changed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is no-way to iterate only on keys, so you have to use

```
ng-repeat="(key, value) in object"
```

you can't ignore value here.

Comment: How am I going to get attribute1 and attribute2 (the *key* values) to use as labels without having a reference to the key? Also, binding to "value" will not update data elsewhere in the controller because each iteration of ng-repeat creates its own scope. Downvoted because I explained most of this in my original question.